# Generating a corresponding name for models in PHP MVC

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, installation

For purposes of learning MVC *(I'm totally new to this)* I am writing a mini-framework of my own. Perhaps my question will be pretty stupid and, for some, obvious, but I really couldn't google it, mainly because I don't know how to google it. Also, sorry for the long, redundant post.

My `Router` class works this way `www.example.com/controller/controller_method`.

All my controllers and models have the same prefix in their names. For example I have the `UsersController` class and the corresponding `UsersModel` class.

Controllers and Models are the instances of the corresponding abstract classes. For instance here's the controller class:

```
abstract class Controller
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

**And now the question.** I'm instantiating the corresponding model inside the controller constructor this way:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(new UsersModel());
    }
}
```

But would it be *right/acceptable/adequate* to do it this way:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $model = str_replace("Controller", "Model", __CLASS__);
        parent::__construct(new $model());
    }
}
```

Or, may be even better, like this:

```
abstract class Controller
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct($classname)
    {
        $model = str_replace("Controller", "Model", $classname);
        $this->model = new $model();
    }
}
```

So the constructor of the child would be:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(__CLASS__);
}
```

This seems more automated but, perhaps, it may be poor/slow/stupid design decision? The main reason I'm worried is that `__CLASS__` constant is magic, and I read somewhere that magic methods/constants can be 2-24x slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to fuss about in the child class:

```
abstract class Controller
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $modelName = str_replace("Controller", "Model", get_class($this));
        $this->model = new $modelName;
    }
}
```

Courtesy of the second answer to this question: [Getting the name of a child class in the parent class (static context)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283004/getting-the-name-of-a-child-class-in-the-parent-class-static-context)

Note: requires php 5.2.9