# How can I get table name, statically from Eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, static-methods, lumen

Right now I have this code to check to which table an Eloquent model is connected into.

```
$s = new Something();
dd($s->getTable());
```

Is there anyway I can get the table without instantiating new `Something` object?

I was thinking something like these codes:

```
Something::getTable();
```

But there will be `..should not be called statically` error.

Comment: You can take a look here : http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: `(new static)->getTable()`

Comment: @Inazo This has nothing to do with just the (French?) documentation of static's in PHP.

Comment: Problem is that the `$table` variable that you could use to specify a custom table name for the model is not static so you can't access it statically. It's weird but also by design. (Read [eloquent model conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) under table names)

Comment: I wrote an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62654389/6212294) that answers your question too. Also, you can get table name by calling a **static function** in this way. There is no need to make a object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return database table name in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082682/how-to-return-database-table-name-in-laravel)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add to your model.

```
public static function getTableName()
{
    return (new self())->getTable();
}
```

Then you can get table name with `Something::getTableName()`

Comment: `get_called_class()` is helpful if you want to define `getTableName()` in a parent model that the actual models extend. https://stackoverflow.com/a/283094/470749

Comment: @Ryan Or `return (new static)->getTable()` in base model.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a slight modification so that you can get a model's table name statically.

1. Define a Trait: `app/Traits/CanGetTableNameStatically.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Traits;

trait CanGetTableNameStatically
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return with(new static)->getTable();
    }
}
```

2. Put in on your `Model`, or better yet, use a `BaseModel` and all your other models extends it.

`app/Models/BaseModel.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\CanGetTableNameStatically;

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    use CanGetTableNameStatically;

    // ...
}
```

3. On your other models, you can set the custom table name on Laravel's reserved attribute: `protected $table`

`app/Models/Customer.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Master;

use App\Models\BaseModel;

class Customer extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'my_customers';

    // ...
}
```

**Usage**: just call `YourModel::tableName()` anywhere.

In Views:

```
{{ \App\Models\Customer::tableName() }}
```

When doing Joins:

```
DB::table( Product::tableName() . ' AS p' )
->leftJoin( ProductCategory::tableName() . ' AS pc', 'pc.id', '=', 'p.category_id')
// ... etc
```

Comment: +1 This is the exact solution I came up with myself when I was looking for the answer and use as needed.

Comment: why make this a trait when it's only used by base model?

Answer (score 4):

Not static but elegant approach

```
with(new Something)->getTable();
```

Comment: Is that really "elegant"? Creating a whole model/object to get one string of info.

Answer (score 3):

Resurrecting this, but it must be said.
Similar problem, ended up doing this to models.

```
    public const TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
    protected $table = self::TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: elegant way that we use many years :)  why laravel didn't use contants for table name by default ?

Comment: I prefer this method also. Just set a convention/policy to always include table name in each model.
The other solutions to create a whole new model just to get one variable name is just weird. I'm using static to reduce memory usage, why then are people suggesting to create a new model to extract just one string 

Answer (score 0):

I think is is a simplest way to do get the model's table name in laravel

```
$table_name = (new ModelName())->getTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write macros to do that.

Write the following macro in the boot method of `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as EloquentBuilder;

EloquentBuilder::macro('tableName', function (): string {
    assert($this instanceof EloquentBuilder);
    return $this->from;
});
```

Now simply call `User::tableName()` to get the table name of the model.

Answer (score -1):

$model = new Model;
echo $model->getTable();
Try this

Comment: that is exaclty what he want to avoid, instantiating new model instance